# What is the meaning of "this" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "this" in the following sentence?

> Something this important required complete privacy.

Is the sentence with "this" a grammatically correct sentence structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sentence, **this** is used in an adverbal sense meaning **to a particular degree**. There are several other ways of expressing the same meaning:

> She had never eaten this much before
>   She had never eaten as much as this before
>  
>   She had never eaten as much before
>  
>   She had never eaten so much before

Note that **this** in the the first example sentence is an adverb, but in the second example sentence it is a pronoun (actually a demonstrative pronoun).

You will find both the pronoun and adverb definitions of **this** in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/this).

Comment: does "Something this important required complete privacy." mean " Something as important required completed privacy" ? then, is "this or as" in the sentences adverbs ?

Comment: Does "Something this important required complete privacy." mean "Something important like this required completed privacy"?

Comment: Yes, **this**, **as** and **so** are all functioning as adverbs of degree. No, you can't replace **this** by **like this***. Adverb**this** is about degree - **how important** something is. **like** is about similarity, for example, similarity of style: "I want to buy another pair of shoes **like** this."

Comment: If so, then, is "this" in the sentence, "She had never eaten as much as this before" adverb not noun?

Comment: In "this much", **this** qualifies the determiner (a kind of adjective) **much**, so it is an adverb. In the expression "as *adjective* as *noun*", it takes the place of a noun: it's actually a demonstrative pronoun. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-and-as-expressions/as-as

Answer (score 3):

> Something this important required complete privacy.

means

> Anything *as important as this thing we are talking about* required complete privacy.

which really means

> *This thing we are talking about* required complete privacy *because it was so important.*

Comment: Does "Something this important required complete privacy." mean "Something required completed privacy because something was so important like this". then, does "this important " in the sentence mean "because something was so important like this" ?

Comment: Does "Something this important required complete privacy." mean "Something important like this required completed privacy"?

Comment: The word "this" in your two sentences are completely difference.  Re-read JavaLatte's answer.  In the original sentence, "this" means "to a particular degree".  "This important" means "as important as this".